# Como eliminar espaço em branco dentre colunas?

Tags: html, css

Tenho a seguinte tabela:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="border-top:1pt solid black">A</td>
    <td style="border-top:1pt solid black">B</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Perceba que ao colocar a borda nas `td's` a linha não tem continuidade de uma coluna para outra, mas possui um intervalo em branco. Como posso remover esse espaço usando `border` na `td` como está?

Resultado obtido:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Resultado desejado:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adicione `style="border-collapse: collapse;"` na tag ou no css:

```css
table {
border-collapse: collapse;
 }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="border-top:1pt solid black">A</td>
    <td style="border-top:1pt solid black">B</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

A tag `TABLE` tem uma prioridade para isso.
Tente o código abaixo:

```
 <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
```

Comment: muito obrigado pela resposta @RogerioSoaresFerreira o único problema é que o atributo `cellspacing` não é suportado no HTML5.